# Which is best way to convert currency price from other currency

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, metatrader4, forex

I am working on NodeJS project where i have All EUR currency, and i need to find another price from EUR

Example: There are two currency that values I have EURUSD and EURAED.

I need to find USDAED, Formula: EURAED/EURUSD = USDAED

But the close price must be equal or between HIGH & LOW prices but after calculation its changes. Formula work with a single price, not if it has open,high,low and close price

**Problem:**

- Many generated currency close price is less than Low or high then High.
- First tick, High is high, then next tick, high less than last high. (Once high go high, it will never go down until day end)

**Question:**
Which is the correct way to find currency prices from other currencies?

Example find USDAED by using EUR market.
[image]

**Example 2: find CADJPY by using USD market** 
[image]

Note: Excel example just for your reference.

Comment: It's not clear what this question is about.  You can't calculate the market `USD:AED` rate from the market `USD:EUR` and `EUR:AED` rates, that's not how the forex market works.  The discrepancies between a direct conversion from one currency to another, and a trip which uses intermediate currencies, gives rise to the opportunity for *arbitrage*.  But none of this is about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cross through the EUR, so for USD/AED the answer is:

**On LHS buy USD / <strike>sell EUR</strike> and sell AED / <strike>buy EUR</strike>**

**On RHS sell USD / <strike>buy EUR</strike> and buy AED / <strike>sell EUR</strike>**

Where the EUR cancels out. However the currencies have to be quoted so that happens. To get USDAED you are asking for a price expressed as # AED per 1 USD. So it is EURAED / EURUSD.

Which is what you've done. The thing is the high for EURUSD has nothing to do with the high for EURAED they are totally unrelated. It makes mathematical sense that when calculating a cross currency Z from base pairs Y / X the limits for the base pairs X and Y are not necessarily the limit for a cross pair Z. The limits (high of the day) for the unrelated base pairs will have happened at different times of day.

[Here's a primer on FX calculations](http://www.webstersystems.co.uk/fxmm.htm#spot%20fx) (disclaimer: I wrote this some time ago).

Comment: 1) So as i understand, to find GBP/JPY OR NZD/AUD i always need USD market price? 
2) i cant use any other market to find USD/AED or GBP/NZD except USD market price?

Comment: you use the most liquid pair, usually through USD but sometimes EUR or a local currency...

Comment: Please check this http://prntscr.com/sbiq0k Now i calculate CAD/JPY with USD market prices. Still error, Close price is low then candle low.

Comment: I don’t think you can find out the high and low of the day for the cross pair. The high for CADJPY would be the high USDJPY divided by the low USDCAD but these didn’t necessarily happen at the same time!